# How to automatically reattach to a process controlled by valgrind from within gdb?

Tags: linux, segmentation-fault, gdb, valgrind

I made a memory error that is quite difficult to debug, happening every once in a few command-line runs, each taking about two hours to complete. Because of that, I thought it could be a good idea to create logs like this:

```
while true; do 
  valgrind ./command 2>&1 | tee command
  grep -q Invalid && break
done
```

The problem is that my debug logs and stack traces produced by Valgrind aren't enough, so I decided to add `--vgdb-error=0` to the command line. Unfortunately, since Valgrind now adds a breakpoint on startup, I need to run the following:

```
$ gdb ./command
...gdb init string follows...
(gdb) target remote | /usr/lib/valgrind/../../bin/vgdb
Remote debugging using | /usr/lib/valgrind/../../bin/vgdb
relaying data between gdb and process 4361
Reading symbols from /lib/ld-linux.so.2...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/ld-linux.so.2
[Switching to Thread 4361]
0x04000840 in ?? () from /lib/ld-linux.so.2
(gdb) continue
Continuing.
```

How can I script the process so that either Valgrind does not break on startup or a script keeps attaching to vgdb processes and tell them to continue until one of the processes completes abnormally?

Comment: If all goes well, I'm getting "Remote connection closed" after `continue`.

Comment: Why not use --vgdb-error=1 and then attach the debugger after it errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument to `--vgdb-error` is the number of errors to expect before valgrind stops the program and attaches the debugger. If you set it to `0`, then it will stop immediately before running your program. You want `--vgdb-error=1`, which will run to the first error then stop. Then you can attach a debugger.